# finding out modified element in an array using XOR property

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, xor

This question is being attempted from [here](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=13718667)

> How to find out modified element in an array?
>
> Eg: Array A= {1,2,3,4,5,6} before modifiction After modification
>   A={1,2,3,7,5,6}. Here the element 4 is replaced with element 7.

Some one used a XOR Property to solve this problem

```
 int getModifiedElement(int arr1[ ],int arr2[ ])
       {
                   int xor1 = arr1[0];
                   int xor2 = arr2[0];
                              for(int i=1;<i<arr1.length;i++)
                              {
                                     xor1 = xor1 ^ arr1[i];
                                     xor2 = xor2 ^ arr2[i];
                              }
             return xor1^xor2;
            }
```

I am not clear with what XOR property has been used to solve the problem?

Comment: This solution is to a different problem. This function returns 1 if there _are_ modified elements and 0 if there are none. It does not return the index/value of the modified values.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `for(int i=0;i<arrLength;i++) { if (arr1[i] ^ arr2[i] != 0) { printf("element %d was replaced by element %d", arr1[i], arr2[i]); } }` work just fine? (of course the print statement should be replaced with a different operation in order to return the values instead of printing them, but, yeah, not a problem of mine...)

Answer (score 2):

`xor` is associative and commutative, so when `xor1` xors together all elements from array 1 and `xor2` those from array 2, the unmodified elements are present in both, so with `xor1 ^ xor2`, they're eliminated because `x ^ x == 0`, so what remains is `old ^ new` in `xor1 ^ xor2`, that is the modification leading from the old to the changed element of the array.

It does, however, neither say what the old element was, nor what the new is, so it does **not** solve the problem as stated.

Comment: Pretty good, so how is 4^7 useful ?

Comment: @cnicutar Good question, we should ask that the author of the code.

Comment: Someone should make a poster "because a loop with a simple test and a break is too mainstream".

Comment: @DanielFischer actually I did not wrote the code if you see the link some one provided the above solution s my doubt is same as that of cnicutar

Comment: @RegisteredUser I gathered that from your question. If you had written it, you'd know what you intended with it. And yes, I think the code doesn't solve the problem too. I just explained what the code does.

Comment: @DanielFischer hmmm even I was thinking the same that the code does not solves the problem.

Comment: @RegisteredUser That, we and ravigupta from the link agree about. I think the Anonymous just learned about `xor` and wanted to apply it to anything, if you got a shiny new hammer...